# Learn Optimal Parameters of Beta Distribution for Bayesian A/B Test

Tags: bayesian, optimization, ab-test

What are the known / efficient methods to learn the parameters of a Beta Distribution in the context of A/B testing?

Is it a reasonable starting point to learn from the history of the base (Let's say form A data which is the base variant)?

Comment: It is absolutely reasonable to start with existing data to form your prior. Just to be clear, the beta is to be used as the prior for a binomial right?

Comment: Yes. But the update rule of the conjugate seems to converge too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Beta Binomial model, a way to do it is to update the posterior with the data.

It can be done by the formula of the conjugate:

[image]

Image from [Wikipedia - Conjugate Prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).